# Is Dreamweaver "upwards" compatible with manually created semantic html?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, semantics

A prospective client has a site with pages done in Dreamweaver(tm).  I don't have Dreamweaver(tm), never use it, and have in the past have seen some spaghetti (html) code on pages created with it.  As a result, I'm wondering: if I create clean sections of semantic html, will Dreamweaver continue to be able to edit it when the client wishes to modify the code that I have created by hand (assuming that I create clean and validating code).  This is more of an experience based question than a research based question.  I'm sure that Dreamweaver(tm)'s documentation would tell me that it's compatible with clean, semantic html, but it's hard to take that advice from the horse's mouth.

So, based on your experience, is Dreamweaver happy with clean semantic html created externally, or does the visual mode display badly when it's dealing with manually, externally-created semantic html?

Comment: Frontwards? Forwards? Bow-wards?

Comment: Sure, you can edit any old HTML. Don't expect it still to be pretty when the client has hacked at it with the blunt instrument that is Dreamweaver, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it is compatible.

It depends on how your clients want to modify the code. Dreamweaver is a good editing tool, and it supports and "understands" semantic (x)html/css. However, if your clients still use html for styling (such as table-based layouts etc.), then proper clean css-styling can be frustrating for them to deal with later. But it is another problem and it has nothing to do with the editor.

Comment: Hmmm, good point about the interaction with their future edits.  I'm wondering what a good solution to that would be, perhaps inline css or something.

Comment: In my experience, inline css doesn't make a code easier to read, but maybe it's just for me. There is no "proper" answer to this. Personally, I would write style guides for a big web site, or simply leave comments at the top of .css stylesheets for a smaller project. Anyway, I would definitely leave comments for those parts of css that can raise questions (workarounds to achieve cross-browser compatibility,classes that work in conjunction with Javascript code, etc). As for editing other people's html/css, I think that Firefox+Firebug+any html/text editor is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Editing HTML in the “code” mode of Dreamweaver leaves it alone. Not sure about the visual mode though.